# Problemas com caracteres no php, com o utf-8. Como resolver?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Criei uma tabela em php que retorna dados do MYSQL no phpadmin, porém as informações retornadas na tabela estão vindo assim:

"Minera��o de Dados e Simula��o"

Repare na interrogação que vem no lugar dos acentos com TIL.

Coloquei UTF8 unicode CI, mas mesmo assim não funfa. Alguma sugestão do que fazer?

Comment: Tenta colocar `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` ou usar função do PHP mesmo, `utf8_decode()` e `utf8_encode()`. Também pode setar o `collation` na conexão com `mysql`, ou alterar o `collation` do próprio arquivo usandp `Notepad++`.

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar também `mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8');`

Answer (score -1):

```
@header( "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1", true );
```

Solução acima.